# Removing internal separator from two grouped UITableView cells

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

I have a grouped `UITableView` that contains two cells. I've set a custom `separatorColor` for the table view, but would like to get rid of the internal separator in between the two cells, so that it looks like one cell. I want to keep the external separator around the edge of the cells.

What I have now:

[image: A grouped table view with two cells and a visible separator]

What I'd like to achieve:

[image: A grouped table view with two cells and no visible separator]

Is this possible? My project is targetting iOS 5.0 and above. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this have to be a dynamic table? you mentioned that it only has two cells.. perhaps you could look at making the table/section one cell with a larger row height? or perhaps not put it in a table at all? instead use a UIView:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [myview.layer setBorderWidth:1];
    [myview.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];
    [myView.layer setCornerRadius:20];
}
```

the above code will give you the rounded corners on any view you desire just swap out the`myview` variable.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing separator style of the table view too.

```
tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Comment: That removes the internal separator but also removes the external separator around the edge of the cells.

Comment: It's better idea to put your own background image.

Answer (score -1):

Try Adding

```
[self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
```

or U can add

```
UIView *backgroundVie = [[UIView alloc] init];
backgroundVie.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundView=backgroundVie ;
```

Comment: That doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Setting the cell background view to a clear view allows the table view background to show through.